# Gráfico de casos acumulados com ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de acordo com o gráfico abaixo de dias após 100 casos confirmados, no caso do meu gráfico, coloquei como dias após 10 casos confirmados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando esse código:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados <- read_delim("~/Downloads/arquivo_geral.csv", 
                    ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
dados <- dados[,-1]

nm_estados <- dados %>% 
  filter(data == max(data))

cgroup_cols <- c(clr_darken(paletteer_d("ggsci::category20_d3"), 0.2)[1:length(nm_estados$estado)], "gray70")

dados %>%
  filter(casosAcumulados > 9) %>%
  mutate(days_elapsed = data - min(data),
         end_label = ifelse(data == max(data), estado, NA),
         end_label = case_when(estado %in% nm_estados$estado ~ end_label, TRUE ~ NA_character_),
         cgroup = case_when(estado %in% nm_estados$estado ~ estado, TRUE ~ "ZZOTHER")) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = days_elapsed, y = casosAcumulados,
                       color = cgroup, label = end_label,
                       group = estado)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5) +
  geom_text_repel(nudge_x = 0.75,
                  segment.color = NA) + 
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cgroup_cols) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format(accuracy = 1),
                     breaks = 2^seq(4, 19, 1),
                     trans = "log2")
```

Porém, meu gráfico não está ajustando o eixo corretamente, com todas as linhas saindo do valor 0. Está ficando da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para as linhas do meu gráfico ficarem da mesma forma do gráfico de exemplo?

Base de dados: https://covid.saude.gov.br/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Com dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dados <- read.csv2('arquivo_geral.csv')

dados %<>%
  filter(casosAcumulados > 9) %>%
  group_by(estado) %>%
  mutate(diasposdez = 1:n())

ggplot(subset(dados, casosAcumulados > 9), aes(diasposdez, casosAcumulados)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = estado)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2')
```

**Com data.table**

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dados <- fread('arquivo_geral.csv')

dados[casosAcumulados > 9, diasposdez := 1:.N, by = estado]

ggplot(dados[casosAcumulados > 9], aes(diasposdez, casosAcumulados)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = estado)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado!